# Keep timer code working after form is closed

Tags: c#

i'm currently making a program with expire date and i want my timer to work even when program is closed, this is my code:

```
    private int counter = 30;
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 day
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            counter--;
            if (counter == 0)
                timer1.Stop();
            label3.Text = counter.ToString();

    }

   private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

i will be happy to know how to do it if its possible to do it

Comment: The timer would have to be declared outside of the form in some class that remains instantiated after this form is closed.

Comment: Surely you added the timer to the wrong form class.  Consider adding it on the Form1 class instead.  Normally the main window of the app so is always around.

Comment: `timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 day`  1 day?  that's 1 second.  If you are trying to expire the program after 30 days, a timer is not the tool you are looking for.

Comment: i know i just tried some codes so i tested it on 1 sec

Comment: If _even when program is closed_ is what you want, it's not possible. Either you'll need some sort of service running in the background, or you'll need to check the time on program start

Comment: You say when your form is closed in the title, but you program closed in the question. Which is it? Depending on what you want. the answers are very different.

Answer (score 0):

If the timer shall keep on counting, even if your program is shut down, you can't use a timer. Use the `DateTime` class instead.

Save the value of DateTime.Now to disk (e.g. with an application setting), then, in order to check for expiry, load that value again, and compare it to the current time:

Assuming `startOfPeriod` is the start of your expiry period:

```
if( startOfPeriod.AddDays( 30 ) < DateTime.Now )
{
// Time has expired
}
```

Note: Be aware, that in this approach, your software can expire in the midth of the day. If you don't want that to happen, replace the above `if` expression with:

```
if( startOfPeriod.Date.AddDays( 30 ) < DateTime.Now.Date )
```